# MySQL bulk insert (ignoring primary key id, but on duplicate update another key)

Tags: mysql, insert, bulkinsert

On a bulk insert, how do I ignore a duplicate key update for primary key 'id' while only updating the entry for another key 'another_unique_id'?

```
INSERT INTO
  some_table (`id`, `another_unique_id`, `raw_data)
  VALUES     (5   ,  'ABCDEFG', 'blah')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...?
```

For example -
If there's a record with id: 5, I don't want to update it.  I'll just insert a new record.

If there's a record with 'ABCDEFG' in the 'another_unique_id' field, then I'd like to update that entry to 'blah'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass

```
INSERT INTO
some_table (`id`, `another_unique_id`, `raw_data)
VALUES     (NULL   ,  'ABCDEFG', 'blah')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...?
```

otherwise it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

At least on mysql you can use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
some_table (`id`, `another_unique_id`, `raw_data`)
VALUES     (5 ,  'ABCDEFG', 'blah')
```

If a field with id 5 exists it will do the same as an update, 
and if it doesn't exist, it will do the same as the regular insert.

Comment: The OP said that if ID 5 already exists he wants to `INSERT`, not `UPDATE`. I think you're suggesting the opposite.